# Is the function $f(x)=[x]\sin(πx)$ continuous?

Tags: analysis

I have a question..Is the function $f(x)=[x]\sin(πx)$ continuous? How can I check it??

Comment: Check that it's continuous on the open set $\mathbb R - \mathbb Z$, then check the limit at each $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @JackM I used this relation: $$(x-1)sin(πx) \leq [x] sin(πx) \leq xsin(πx)$$ Could you tell me if it is right???

Comment: Assuming your [x] is the floor function your first inequality is **wrong**. Take $x=-2.5$ then 
$(x-1)\sin (x\pi) = 3.5$ and $\lfloor x-1\rfloor \sin (x\pi) = 3$

Comment: @gammatester Why is it wrong??? Isn't it $[x]\leq x \leq [x]+1$ ?

Comment: Sure, but what happens if you multiply this inequality with a negative number?

Comment: @gammatester So,do I have to take cases?? And if it was $sin(πx)>0$,would it be right??

Comment: Yes it is right if $\sin(\pi x) > 0.$ But I would not use these inequalities and argument like JackM. Floor is discontinous for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $f$ is continous in $x \not \in \mathbb{Z}$ as a product of two continous functions. What are the limits of $f(z^{-})$ and $f(z^{+})$ for $z \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: First rule that you have to apply if you didn't already: plot the function. You can use wolfram, [on this page for example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor%28x%29*sin%28pi*x%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
f(x)=n\sin(\pi x), \quad x \in [n,n+1), \ n\in \mathbb{Z}
$$
the function $f$ is continuous on 
$$
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}[n,n+1)=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
f(n-\varepsilon)&=&[n-\varepsilon]\sin((n-\varepsilon)\pi)=(n-1)(-1)^{n+1}\sin(\varepsilon\pi)\\
f(n+\varepsilon)&=&[n-\varepsilon]\sin((n+\varepsilon)\pi)=n(-1)^n\sin(\varepsilon\pi),
\end{eqnarray}
it follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to n^-}f(x)&=&\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}f(n-\varepsilon)=0=f(0)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}f(n+\varepsilon)=\lim_{x\to n^+}f(x).
\end{eqnarray}
Hence $f$ is continuous at any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I understand.....Thank you!